# How do I get the last n objects of a django query?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to display a chat log in django. I can get my entire chatlog in the proper order with this query.

```
latest_chats_list = Chat.objects.order_by('timestamp')
```

I want the functionality of this line (last 10 elements in order), but django doesn't allow negative indexes.

```
latest_chats_list = Chat.objects.order_by('timestamp')[-10:]
```

if I try this line, I get the messages I want, but they're in the wrong order.

```
latest_chats_list = Chat.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:10]
```

This line gives the first 10 chats instead of the most recent.

```
latest_chats_list = Chat.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:10].reverse()
```

Answer (score 11):

```
last_ten = Chat.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
last_ten_in_ascending_order = reversed(last_ten)
```

### Edit (from comments)

Why not use Django's [`queryset.reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#reverse) ?

Because it messes with the SQL query, as does `queryset.order_by()`. Slicing the queryset (`[:10]`) also alters the SQL query, adding `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to it. The two can combine in not-obviously-expected ways...

On the other hand, the built-in Python function [`reversed(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) only changes the way queryset gets iterated over, not effecting the SQL at all.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I have some questions. Why did you decide to order by id instead of timestamp? And why the different behavior with reversed(last_ten) and last_ten.reverse()?

Comment: `queryset.reverse()` messes with SQL query, as does `queryset.order_by()`. Slicing the queryset (the `[:10]`) also alters the SQL query, adding `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to it. The two can combine in not-obviously-expected ways...  `reversed(iterable)` on the other hand only changes the way queryset gets iterated over, not effecting the SQL at all.  Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#reverse  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed

Comment: That was a great explanation of what this code does, but unfortunately it is sitting in the comments and not near the code in your answer. For future visitors with this question, could you integrate the explanation into your answer?

Comment: what if my id is UUID? This answer is not generic.